# CRUD users in django , outside of django Admin

Tags: django, django-models

In my current project, I'd like to **CRUD** users **OUTSIDE** of django's Admin interface.

Let's explain my question as following:

1- I'm using the [`UserProfile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) for storing additional attributes for users (their schools, birthday, etc.)

2- The problem is that by deleting a user, I can delete the profile rather than actual `User`.

Please take at the code for Listing and Deleting Users:

```
def user_list(request):
    ''' Shows all of Students '''

    return object_list(request,
            queryset = UserProfile.objects.all() ,
            template_name = 'user_list.html' ,
            template_object_name = 'student'
            )


def user_delete(request , id):
    ''' Deletes a student based on his/her ID '''

    return delete_object(request,
            model = UserProfile ,
            object_id  = id ,
            template_name = 'delete_student.html' ,
            post_delete_redirect = reverse("user_list")
            )
```

It looks normal that I'm deleting `UserProfile` rather than `User`. But I intended it to be a **proxy** to actual `User`.  Do I miss something here ?

3- Generally speaking, should I reference each models to `User` or `UserProfile` ? For example assume that I have a model for Course. Which of these is the correct way?

```
class Course(models.Model):
    #stuff

    student = models.ForeignKey(Urer) 
    # OR ??
    student = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks normal that I'm deleting UserProfile rather than User. But I intended it to a proxy to actual User

Why not delete the User directly? By default, Django will CASCADE DELETE to get rid of the UserProfile as well.

> Generally speaking, should I reference each models to User or UserProfile

I think this is more a question of personal preference, but I usually tie to User directly as it saves a step when getting to the object you want (you don't need to do user.get_profile().student and can call user.student instead). It also makes more sense to me anyway: the student is a property of the user, not the user's profile.